# Copy-Paste from outlook messages also copies U+200e (Left to right marker)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I copy text from a message that I received in MS Outlook, it often (if not in *all* cases) also includes one or more **U+200e** "characters" which seem to be a `left to right markers`.

These were not sent.

I have absolutely no use for them, in fact, the really annoy me.

I guess this is some obscure setting with Outlook that I need to turn off, but I have no idea which one this could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy text & paste into another email:  in Outlook, use Tools > Options, and on the Mail Format tab, click Editor Options (at the bottom); choose Advanced on the left, and scroll down on the right to the "Cut, Copy and Paste" section.

There change the "Pasting between emails" option to "Keep Text Only".

For the sender:  in Outlook, use Tools > Options, and on the Mail Format tab, make sure that RTF is not selected.  These characters actually are in the email you're receiving, they're just not visible when you read the email.